# Non adjacent cells in excel using INDIRECT function

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a formula to find only alpha numeric number in the cells and ignore the rest of the numbers and sum the values of the alpha numeric numbers alone. the formula I tired is working if I choose a range of cells. But I want to apply this only to alternate cells so I used INDIRECT function. I could see the indirect function is not grepping the values in the cell hence it fails. Can someone help me on this.

[image]

Attached, the sample excel pattern used

Formula working for continuous cells  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(A2:F2,LEN(A2:F2)-1)),0))
```

Formula not working for non adjacent cells:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(INDIRECT({"A2","C2","E2"}),LEN(INDIRECT({"A2","C2","E2"}))-1)),0))
```

In this I could see `INDIRECT({"A2","C2","E2"})` itself is not returning the value of `A2`,`C2`,`E2`.

Comment: If Your after alpha numeric only, why is `A2` part of the formula? Just to make sure i understand, its still just the alpha numeric you wanna sum?

Answer (score 0):

Try this array-entered formula:

```
{=SUM(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(T(OFFSET(A2,0,{0,2,4},1,1)),LEN(T(OFFSET(A2,0,{0,2,4},1,1)))-1)),0))}
```